# Are custom fields on Managed package objects deleted when upgrading the package?

Tags: managed-package, custom-field

If I have a managed package installed and I then add a Custom Field to one of the managed package Custom Objects, I then recieve a push upgrade of the managed package, would the Custom Field that I have created on the managed package custom object be deleted by the push upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom Fields that you add outside of the managed package will not be affected by upgrading the managed package.

See the [packaging guide](https://na3.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf) for more details.